# RestSharp Array Request

Tags: c#, .net, json, restsharp

Send array post RestSharp?
 Dictionary, List<> is not compatibile ?

```
public class Test
{
    public string key { get; set; }
    public string viewType { get; set; }
    public string module { get; set; }
    public string method { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<string, string> parameters { get; set; }
}
```

My class init.

```
Test t = new Test();

            t.key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
            t.viewType = "json";
            t.module = "test";
            t.method = "test";

            t.parameters = new Dictionary<string,string>();
            t.parameters.Add("p1", "data1");
```

Send data request

```
 IRestResponse response = restClient.Execute<Test>(restRequest);
```

Send is debbuger:

```
[JSON]
  -request
       module: "test"
       method: "test"
       parameters:"System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]"
```

Who RestSharp create ? ? Send Array options object ?

```
$postData = array(
  'key' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  'viewType' => 'json',
  'module' => 'test',
  'method' => 'test',
  [options] => stdClass Object
  (
    [name] => 'ADIDAS'
  )
);
```

Comment: Add the code that creates and initializes the request.

Comment: Is add  initializes the request

Comment: You still haven't added the code that creates and initializes the `restRequest` object.

Comment: Test t = new Test();

            t.key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
            t.viewType = "json";
            t.module = "test";
            t.method = "test";

            t.parameters = new Dictionary<string,string>();
            t.parameters.Add("p1", "data1");

 IRestResponse response = restClient.Execute<Test>(restRequest);

Comment: I mean the `RestRequest` class object, not the `Test` class object.

Comment: Add the code that creates the `restRequest` before you call `.Execute<Test>(restRequest);`

Comment: RestClient restClient = new RestClient("https:");

                RestRequest restRequest = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
             
                Test t = new Test();

                t.key = ac.Password;
                t.viewType = "json";
                t.module = "hello";
                t.method = "hello";
              
                t.parameters = new Dictionary<string,string>();
                t.parameters.Add("wddwdw", "ddd");
               
   
                restRequest.AddObject(t);

Answer (score 2):

I found this in the documentation:

> To add all properties for an object as parameters, use AddObject(). To
>   add a file for upload, use AddFile() (request will be sent as
>   multipart encoded form). To include a request body (like XML or JSON),
>   use AddBody();

So because you are using `restRequest.AddObject()`, RestSharp uses the value of `t.parameters.ToString()` instead of serializing to JSON.

Fix: use `restRequest.AddBody(t)` instead. You also have to specify the content type.

```
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
request.AddBody(t);
```

Comment: You also have to set the content type.

Comment: request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
request.AddBody(t);

 not send data .....

Answer (score 0):

```
RestClient restClient = new RestClient("https:");

            RestRequest restRequest = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

            Test t = new Test();

            t.key = ac.Password;
            t.viewType = "json";
            t.module = "hello";
            t.method = "hello";

            t.parameters = new Dictionary<string,string>();
            t.parameters.Add("wddwdw", "ddd");


            restRequest.AddObject(t);

 IRestResponse response = restClient.Execute<Test>(restRequest);
```